# SonataMediaBundle - Using twig helper to render image

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata

I'm following [this documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/helpers.html) and I'm trying to figure out what other parameter values can the media helper take to render images.

```
{% media media, 'small' %}
```

In the above example, the media tag takes two parameters, the first one is the media entity and the second one is the format. However, I don't see the list of values for the format in the documentation.

Since {% media %} is a custom twig tag. I tried to put break points on MediaTokenParser and MediaNode but it doesn't seem to stop on those two places. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to find out the values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the formats yourself.

Go to [this link](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html#id1) and scroll down to the `app/config/config.yml` section. By 'default', there are just two formats defined, but you can add your own, and name them according to your preference, like this.

```
        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
```

Basically, you can set `width`, `height` and `quality` in the current code.

There's more examples [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html#advanced-configuration) (they seem to have mixed up the `quality` and `width` attributes in the TV section).

As a side note, a full text search over the source code is always a good idea. If you happen to use Linux, a quick `rgrep "small" * --color` gives you a few pointers to where to look next. `rgrep "quality" * --color` pretty much nails it, leading you to the `Resizer` classes where these options are processed.